# javascript executed more than one

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

at the first I consider both if and else block executed. After added debugger to code, I don't know why my code run more than once.

```js
function Submit(form) {
  var timer_starttime = document.getElementById("timer_starttime");
  var timer_finishtime = document.getElementById("timer_finishtime");
  if (wait_s.reportValidity() && wait_m.reportValidity()) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // new HttpRequest instance 
    var theUrl = "/submit_program";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //document.getElementById("ajax_res").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("success-alert").className = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible";
        console.log(this.responseText);
        console.log("if");
        debugger;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("error-alert").className = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible";
        console.log("else");
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
      "timer_finishtime": timer_finishtime.value,
      "timer_starttime": timer_starttime.value
    }));
  }
  return false;
}
console.log("end");
```

```html
<form id="TimeForm" action="" method="POST">
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return Submit(this);">Save</button>
```

Comment: your `<script>` is inside a `<form>` ?!

Comment: @MisterJojo so what is the issue with that?

Comment: onreadystatechange fires more than once. Ajax 101

Comment: @epascarello What is the problem ? I shouldn't ask this kind of question?

Comment: There is no issue with sticking a script inside of a form. Not sure what your comment was trying to prove.

Comment: @epascarello you're not telling me anything here that I don't already know. This is a question I ask the PO

Comment: You did not ask a question. Your comment sounds like a statement to me. Maybe you meant to say "Is your script inside of a form?" which still would make no difference it was or was not.

Comment: @epascarello I see, now you're going after my poor command of English... what will be the next salvo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send an AJAX request, the request goes through a number of states. See the documentation of [`XMLHttpRequest.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) for the full details.

The `onreadystatechange` function will be called each time the state changes. So your `else` block will be executed repeatedly for all the initial states. Then when the request completes successfully, the `if` block will be executed.

You should only check for an error in the final state `4`, not treat all the other states as errors.

```js
function Submit(form) {
  var timer_starttime = document.getElementById("timer_starttime");
  var timer_finishtime = document.getElementById("timer_finishtime");
  if (wait_s.reportValidity() && wait_m.reportValidity()) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // new HttpRequest instance 
    var theUrl = "/submit_program";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
          //document.getElementById("ajax_res").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          document.getElementById("success-alert").className = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible";
          console.log(this.responseText);
          console.log("if");
          debugger;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("error-alert").className = "alert alert-danger alert-dismissible";
          console.log("else");
        }
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({
      "timer_finishtime": timer_finishtime.value,
      "timer_starttime": timer_starttime.value
    }));
  }
  return false;
}
console.log("end");
```

```html
<form id="TimeForm" action="" method="POST">
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return Submit(this);">Save</button>
```

Comment: Or just use `onload`

Comment: @epascarello True, but then also `onerror`. And of course, modern code should use `fetch()`